# Qt Memory Checked using Valgrind

Tags: c++, qt, valgrind

I am checking for memory leaks in my app for using valgrind and I have this error message :
[image]

When i click on the link, it lead to :

```
QJsonObject obj = prop->m_propertiesObject.at(i).toObject();
QString name = obj.value("name").toString();
QString typeprop = obj.value("type").toString();
QString value = QString::number(obj.value("default").toInt());
```

My question, is this memory leak come from Qt or from my code?

Comment: what is the variable prop? I see that AddNewAnimation take pointer arguments. Are they guarantee to be freed?

Comment: Hi UmNyobe, after check it, you are right. The problem was come from prop. After i freed that one, everything comes good.